# Azure ServiceBusClient CreateReceiver within .Net Core API

Tags: azure, servicebus

This is my first foray with Service Bus, I'm not sure if my plan is performant or best practice.

**Main application is old webforms over SQL hosted in a private cloud (system of record)**

**New application .Net Core API in Azure over Azure DB with React front end.**

Users will create records in the main application, for certain users some records need to be automatically available in the new application.  Rather than creating a API client in the old webforms it seems a perfect use for service bus.  I have this side sending messages just fine and is not the part I have questions on.

I know I can do this but really should I? initial testing has gone well so far.

In the API I have a receiver setup to pull a nth number of messages & pass them to the appropriate handlers.  The handler will decide to complete or deadletter the message.  Once that is complete it ratchets through the messages and waits for a new messages to arrive.  Currently pulling a single message at a time however I have tested unrestricted.

```
public class ServiceBusMessageReceiver : IServiceBusMessageReceiver
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IServiceBusMessageHandlerService _handlerService;
        private ServiceBusClient _client;
        public ServiceBusMessageReceiver(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceBusMessageHandlerService handlerService)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _handlerService = handlerService;
        }
        public async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
        {
            _client ??= new ServiceBusClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ServiceBusUrl"));
            try
            {
                await Listen();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO:Logger
                //Did the message lock expire?
                await ReceiveMessagesAsync();
            }
        }

        private async Task Listen()
        {
            var receiver = _client.CreateReceiver(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ServiceBusQueue"));
            await _handlerService.DelegateMessage(await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(maxMessages: 1), receiver);
            await ReceiveMessagesAsync();
        }

    }
```

In Startup.cs

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceBusMessageReceiver>().ReceiveMessagesAsync();
            });
```

If things stop processing I have a controller I can call to poke the listener.

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: Sorry, is what I'm doing with the receiver going to have performance or reliability issues?